# Looping through multiple object values that are arrays and matching the correct values from another object full of arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, object

My wording was not great but you should be able to get the gist of what I am saying when you see my code.

I have an `object` that looks like this (called `newObj` in my attempted solution below):

```
2020-05-03: (8) ["2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-05-10"]
2020-05-10: (8) ["2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-16", "2020-05-17"]
2020-05-17: (6) ["2020-05-17", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21", "2020-05-22"]
```

The keys need to remain dates, since it will be going on the x-axis of my line graph.

Now, I need to loop through each array of dates above and determine if said date matches the `pickup_date` value in the object below (`object` called `loads` in my attempted solution below) and then add it to `newObj`:

```
0: {id: 167, pickup_date: "2020-05-21", pickup_location: "Sugar Creek, MO 64050, USA", rate: "1000.0", delivery_date: "2020-05-22", …}
1: {id: 768, pickup_date: "2020-05-19", pickup_location: "North Kansas City, MO 64116, USA", rate: "450.0", delivery_date: "2020-05-20", …}
2: {id: 809, pickup_date: "2020-05-20", pickup_location: "Wichita, KS 67219, USA", rate: "454.3", delivery_date: "2020-05-20", …}
3: {id: 984, pickup_date: "2020-05-19", pickup_location: "Fulton, MO 65251, USA", rate: "650.0", delivery_date: "2020-05-20", …}
4: {id: 1232, pickup_date: "2020-05-19", pickup_location: "Shawnee, KS 66219, USA", rate: "1209.62", delivery_date: "2020-05-19", …}
5: {id: 1317, pickup_date: "2020-05-20", pickup_location: "Shawnee, KS 66219, USA", rate: "1209.62", delivery_date: "2020-05-20", …}
6: {id: 1321, pickup_date: "2020-05-21", pickup_location: "Sugar Creek, MO 64058, USA", rate: "550.0", delivery_date: "2020-05-21", …}
7: {id: 1325, pickup_date: "2020-05-18", pickup_location: "Kansas City, MO 64120, USA", rate: "903.6", delivery_date: "2020-05-18", …}
8: {id: 1326, pickup_date: "2020-05-21", pickup_location: "Kansas City, MO 64120, USA", rate: "838.6", delivery_date: "2020-05-21", …}
9: {id: 1451, pickup_date: "2020-05-13", pickup_location: "Kansas City, MO 64127, USA", rate: "575.0", delivery_date: "2020-05-14", …}
```

Basically, the initial `object` contains a week worth of dates.  I want to find all the dates from my second array of `objects` and keep them paired up with the correct `key`.

I have tried many things and I end up with two results; I either only get the last element in my `newObj` value or I get the `array` length for the value of `newObj` (which is the correct length... that is how many loads would actually be in the `array` but I can't access them).

Here is my code:

```
for(property in newObj){
          newObj[property].forEach(function(date){
            loads.forEach(function(load){
              if (load.pickup_date === date){
                newObj[property] = arr.push(load)
              }
            })
          })
        }
        console.log(newObj)
```

This is the console with the correct array length; just not the actual loads...

```
2020-05-03: 34
2020-05-10: 68
2020-05-17: 95
```

Those have to be the correct lengths of some imaginary array but I have no idea how to actually get the data.

Comment: It seems that you copied your code directly from the console, but those lines are both incomplete and unworkable. Can you fix your code and create a snippet which we can execute and review. See the `<>` icon in the text editor to create a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?：

```js
let finalRes = {}
for(property in newObj){
          let arr = []
          newObj[property].forEach(function(date){
            loads.forEach(function(load){
              if (load.pickup_date === date){
                arr.push(load)
              }
            })
          })
         finalRes[property] = arr
        }
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  I was close too :/.  Thanks for the help!